# AngularJS + Node: Blank page when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

Let me start by stating I have never built my own app and deployed it to Heroku.  Now that I am trying, I have debugged my way through some issues, but now it seems as though my app is loading without any errors (according to the console), but my angular app homepage is completely blank.

After adding some non-angular code outside of the `<ui-view></ui-view>` tags, that plain HTML (`<h1>Working?</h1>`) loads, but not the angular.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>EDGE !</title>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular-trello/dist/angular-trello.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
        <script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=87b220f4687be5f86544b866eef24b3e"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="EDGE-Trello">
        <h1>Working?</h1>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there something about deployment that I am missing?  When I look at Network in my Chrome DevTools, it appears as though everything is loading other than one item which shows this error when I type `heroku logs`:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/diseases" host=edge-trello.herokuapp.com request_id=4b16315c-b87e-4ef7-b412-5345881df031 fwd="172.85.41.122" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30008ms status=503 bytes=0
```

...this asset has no problem loading locally and I don't know why there is a problem now.

Here is my route causing the issue:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Disease = mongoose.model('Disease');

router.post('/diseases', function(req, res, next) {
  var disease = new Disease(req.body);

  disease.save(function(err, diseases){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(diseases);
  });
});
```

...and my `disease` factory:

```
app.factory('diseases', [
    '$http',
    function($http){

        var o = {
            diseases: []
        };

        o.show = function(disease) {
            return $http.get('/diseases/', {id : disease._id})
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(disease.name);
            });
        };

        o.create = function(diseases) {
            return $http.post('/diseases', diseases).success(function(data){
                o.diseases.push(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        };

        o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/diseases').success(function(data){
                angular.copy(data, o.diseases);
//              console.log(data);
            });
        };

        o.destroy = function(disease) {
            return $http.delete('diseases/' + disease._id).success(function(data){
                console.log("Disease " + disease.name + " has been removed!");
                o.getAll();
            });
        };

        return o;
    }
]);
```

..and my config function:

```
app.config([
    'TrelloApiProvider', 
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function(TrelloApiProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/javascripts/home/_home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                diseasePromise: ['diseases', function(diseases){
                    return diseases.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
```

Any help in deployment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be an issue with your Angluar routing? maybe post the routes here?

Comment: I'll edit with the routes

Comment: have you set environment variables?

Comment: @you ... I'm not sure

Comment: I had the same issue, the only thing that worked for me was to remove all my cache and cookies (just remove all data on you browser)

Answer (score 0):

Check your network console, you have a call to `/diseases` which returns a 500 server error. Reading your code, you should provide some id to this call.

Comment: I'll add it to the question

Comment: It says "pending" for the status of `/diseases` and then switches to a `503 error`